# Using keyboard text shortcuts in word

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut, microsoft

I created some text "shortcuts" (well..not very short) in Keyboard. For example, when I type `\alpha` I get `α`, and if I type `\sigma` I get `σ`. While this works in almost everything on my computer, it doesn't work in Microsoft Office (e.g., Word and PowerPoint). I wonder if there is a way to make these shortcuts also work in MS Office. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MS Office products live in the own world.

So to make the Alpha and Sigma words be replaced with Greek symbols you need to do following.

Open Word- Preference.

Now choose the Auto Correct

There is a field called Replace -With where you can now do that.

See this example:

[image: alpha sigma]

Use same process for PowerPoint.

Comment: I wonder whether Word for Mac has the same feature as Word for Windows: if you open the “Math AutoCorrect” tab, there is a checkbox for applying math autocorrection outside formulas, too (i.e. outside formulas constructed using Equation Tools). And math autocorrection has a large number of “corrections” *predefined*, e.g. `\alpha` produces α.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela good point, care to make that a question!